# Identify single tap gesture within some time interval android

Tags: android, view, action, gesture, tap

i want to perform some operation when user holds his finger on screen for 2 second(Time may vary). and single tap gesture.
i included gesture detection and used Motion Events methods like ActionDown and ActionUp but i couldn't handle long press and single tap gesture... Any Solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) and [OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html)?